How to control width of .hconcat subplot
I am trying to concatenate two graphs, with the one on the beign dependent on the selection made on the graph on the left. The problem is that the right graph is a bar type, and depending on the selection, the bar may be big and occupy a lot of space, making me lose some information, like the legend (see image).
How can I control the concatenated graph dimensions, so it won't happen?
PS: I tried not the using 'empty = 'none'' argument on the selection. Although it fixes the issue above, it creates another: it makes the new graph very difficult to read. I want to use empty = none so it shows only the bars of the selected category.
from vega_datasets import data
import altair as alt

gm = data.gapminder()
gm2005 = gm[gm.year == 2005]

selecao = alt.selection_single(fields=['cluster'], empty = 'none')

linhas = alt.Chart(gm).mark_line().encode(
    x = 'year:T',
    y = alt.Y('mean(life_expect):Q', scale = alt.Scale(zero = False)),
    color = 'cluster:N'
).add_selection(selecao)

barras = alt.Chart(gm).mark_bar().encode(
    y = 'country',
    x = 'life_expect',
).transform_filter(
    selecao
).properties(
    height = 300)

linhas | barras

[Graph before selection][https://i.sstatic.net/lQUtkk89.png]
Graph with hidden info

To control the width you can use width inside properties. I'm guessing this is not what you are after since you already know how to use height. Could you elaborate on what it is you want to do or try to explain it in another way?
